# Оптимизация сложного sql запроса

Tags: mysql

Изначально sql-запрос был такой:

```
SELECT
   b.*,
   cities.translate as citytr,
   cities.title_ru as cityname,
   (
      SELECT
         COUNT(*) 
      FROM
         board_favorites bf 
      WHERE
         bf.board_id = b.id 
         AND user_id = '0'
   )
   AS `countfav` 
FROM
   board b 
   join
      (
         select
            id 
         from
            board 
         WHERE
            CONCAT(', ', `cat_id`, ', ') LIKE '%, 9, %' 
            AND `id` > '0' 
            AND `city_id` = '1' 
            AND status = '1' 
            AND activation = '1' 
            AND `del` = '0' 
         ORDER BY
            `id` DESC LIMIT 0,
            20
      )
      b2 
      on b.id = b2.id 
   left join
      cities 
      on b.city_id = cities.city_id
```

Но из-за LIKE по идее не работает индекс.

Теперь пробую такой:

```
SELECT
   b.*,
   `board`.*,
   `board_favorites`.*,
   (
      SELECT
         COUNT(`board_id`) 
      FROM
         `board_favorites` 
      WHERE
         `board_favorites`.`board_id` = b.`board_id` 
         AND `user_id` = '1'
   )
   AS `countfav` 
FROM
   `board_category` b 
   left join
      `board` 
      on b.board_id = board.id 
   left join
      `board_favorites` 
      on b.board_id = board_favorites.board_id 
WHERE
   b.`cat_id` = 9 
   AND b.`board_id` = `board`.`id` 
   AND `id` > '0' 
   AND `city_id` = '1' 
   AND `status` = '1' 
   AND `activation` = '1' 
   AND `del` = '0' 
ORDER BY
   `id` DESC LIMIT 20000,
   20
```

С сортировкой и лимитом выполняется в разы дольше чем без них. У таблицы board имеется составной индекс на city_id, status, activation, del Именно в таком порядке. У таблицы board_category стоят индексы на cat_id и board_id. У board_favorites индексы на user_id и board_id.

Можно как-то ускорить работу с сортировкой и лимитом?

---

Структура БД (портянка ещё та)

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `board`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `board`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board` (
`id` int(11) auto_increment,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cat_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`translate` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(15000) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`person` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`region_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`photo` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timeupdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timesrok` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` enum ('1','2') NOT NULL default '2',
`activation` enum ('1','2') NOT NULL default '1',
`torg` enum ('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`free` enum ('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`vip` enum ('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
`viptime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`select` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`selecttime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`confirm` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sendemail` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type` enum('1','2') NOT NULL default '1',
`del` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`file` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`views` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`url` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
`lat` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`lng` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

--
-- Структура таблицы `board_category`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `board_category`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board_category` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`board_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
KEY `board_id` (`board_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) уже смотрел?

Comment: Вот explain - http://joxi.ru/p27LjXBi0O93WA

Comment: Сортировка работает столько, сколько она работает. А limit сначала пройдет 20000 строк и только потом выдаст 20. По названиям полей с запросе невозможно понять из каких они таблиц, а следовательно и посоветовать чего либо невозможно, не понимая структуру БД. Вообще стоит попробовать изменить подход и избежать применения limit с таким большим смещением. Например получив нужные несколько записей предварительно в подзапросе, а потом уже к ним подклеивать все остальное. И особенно тот подзапрос, что в списке выборки. сейчас он у вас выполняется 20020 раз

Comment: Дополнил свой пост.

Comment: @Mike, добавил структуру БД.

Comment: А почему board клеится по left join ? Вы хотите получить одну запись категории в случае, если в board нет подходящих записей ? так вы ее все равно не получите, потому что в where есть условия по таблице board и на null вы не проверяете. А что до индекса city_id, status, activation, del думаю он в принципе не может быть использован, потому что выдает слишком много записей и среди них с нужной категорией не такой уж и большой процент.

Comment: Для начала стоит понять какая из частей тормозит. Для начала я бы выбросил подзапрос из списка выборки и посмотрел к чему это приводит со скоростью. И что то я не понял, почему первый запрос, превратился во второй, они дают совершенно разные данные

Comment: @Mike, с джоинами не очень дружу, но в первом нормально работает и просто join.
Подзапрос выбросил, скорость выполнения та же.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что везде простого join должно быть достаточно. left следует применять только тогда, когда он действительно нужен. во всех остальных случаях, он может оказывать нежелательное (или желательное) воздействие на оптимизатор, в итоге сильно влиять на скорость. хотя думаю в вашем случае сильно не скажется

Comment: И в любом случае сортировка будет долгой, если под условия выборки попадает много строк. хотя может поможет индекс boadr_id, cat_id на board_category, хотя мне странно, почему бы он тормозил, если там как думает оптимизатор действительно порядка 23 тыс строк

Comment: @Mike, у board_category есть эти индексы http://joxi.ru/zAN5XO9flENRe2

Comment: Сервер на digitalocean, скорость чтения с диска хорошая. Настройки mysql почти не менял, только кеширование включил. Драйвер или как его там, MariaDB.

Comment: У вас 2 отдельных индекса. Вам же надо найти категорию и внутри нее получить отсортированный список board_id (так по крайней мере сейчас делает оптимизатор в вашем запросе, причем с помощью filesort). Вот если бы у вас был индекс из двух полей cat_id, board_id (в таком порядке, в предыдущем посте я ошибся) он бы мог встать на категорию и идти внутри нее по порядку board_id, прямо по индексу. Если оптимизатор не поймет этого, то явно указать в order_by cat_id, board_id

Comment: @Mike, explain первого запроса http://joxi.ru/V2VeJ89T0wWEKm он выполняется за 0,04 секунды
Второго http://joxi.ru/xAeewRKTY0eJPA и выполняется 0.4 секунды.